# Duplicate value postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have an entry in the database

```
|   group   |   account   |   description   |   balance   |   balance1   |
+----------+-------------+-----------------+-------------+--------------+
|  123123  |       0     |      Name 1     |    1000.00  |      0       |
|  123123  |      777    |      Name 2     |     250.00  |      0       |
|  123123  |      999    |      Name 3     |       0     |     350.00   |
|  123000  |       0     |      Name 4     |     500.00  |      0       |
|  123000  |      567    |      Name 5     |       0     |     500.00   |
```

select

```
select * from table;
```

Gives exactly the same result as the example above.

I would like to get the result without duplicates in the "group" column. Here's one:

```
|   group   |   account   |   description   |   balance   |   balance1   |
+----------+-------------+-----------------+-------------+--------------+
|  123123  |       0     |      Name 1     |    1000.00  |      0       |
|          |      777    |      Name 2     |     250.00  |      0       |
|          |      999    |      Name 3     |       0     |     350.00   |
|  123000  |       0     |      Name 4     |     500.00  |      0       |
|          |      567    |      Name 5     |       0     |     500.00   |
```

That is, as you can see from the example, I want to remove only duplicate values ​​from the first column, without affecting the rest.
Also "group by", "order by" I can't use, as it will break the sequence of information output.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? That makes no sense to me

Comment: SQL wasn't designed to do this kind of formatting. That's much better done in your application when you _display_ those results.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I am writing my application in Spring. The point is that this is a table that I need to parse from xml. Everything is fine with parsing) The data is written as in my example (this example is not shown here). But when in my application I try to collect data in a Map, they are not displayed correctly on the front. So I had this idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might work for you:

```
with cte as 
    (
        SELECT goup, account, description, balance, balance1, 
        row_number() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) as rn 
        FROM yourtable
    )
SELECT case when LAG(goup) OVER (ORDER BY rn) = goup THEN NULL ELSE goup END AS goup,
    account, description, balance, balance1
FROM cte;
```

`ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)` is a fairly horrible hack.  It is there because `row_number()` requires an `ORDER BY` but you specifically stated that you can't use an order by.  The `row_number()` is however needed in order to use `LAG`, which itself requires an `OVER (ORDER BY..)`.

Very much a case of caveat emptor, but it might give you what you are looking for.

Comment: `order by NULL`  works as well BTW, but @Alexander needs to use soem columns from the table to get *deterministic* result; e.g. `order by account`